# Retrieving Value from Object Store Mulesoft

Tags: mulesoft

I'm trying to store a simple string key value pair in the object store but when I tried to retrieve the value using the key, the value becomes byte[] type. Is there a configuration that converts the string value to byte[] type?

```
<os:store objectStore="SubjectObjectStore" key="#[payload.subjectId]">
  <os:value><![CDATA[#[payload.subjectName]]]></os:value>
</os:store>
```

Both subjectId and subjectName are String type.

Comment: What are you storing originally? Please provide any examples.

Comment: Updated with sample codes.

Comment: Where are you trying to run this code? Anypoint Studio, On Prem server or Cloudhub (with or without OSV2 enabled)?

Comment: I'm running this in Anypoint Studio.